# androidアプリで作ったcsvファイルをPCへ取り出したい

Tags: android, adb

androidアプリでcsvファイルを作ったのですが、そのファイルの取り出し方がわかりません。
コマンドプロンプトで端末にログインしアプリのユーザーを変えてtest.csvファイルが作られたことは確認できました。

```
  C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools> adb shell
  shell@hammerhead:/ $ run-as eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance
  shell@hammerhead:/data/data/eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance $ ls
  cache
  files
  lib
  out
  shell@hammerhead:/data/data/eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance $ ls files
  t1.csv
  test.csv
```

このtest.csvを取り出す方法として下のサイトを参考に実行してみましたがうまくいきません。

[実機デバッグでdata/dataに保存したファイルを取得する方法](http://to-developer.com/blog/?p=1111)
[実機のSQLiteへアクセスできないときの暫定回避策](http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-sqlite/)
[アプリの内部メモリを覗くとパーミッションでブロックされる](https://akira-watson.com/android/adb_run-as.html)

pullができる場所にtest.csvをコピーしようとするところでエラーが出てしまいます。

```
shell@hammerhead:/data/data/eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance$
cat files/test.csv > /storage/ sdcard0/ test.csv
sh: can't create /storage/: Is a directory
sh: cat: /data/data/: Permission denied

cshell@hammerhead:/data/data/eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance$
cat /data/data/ eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance/files/test.csv > /storage/ sdcard0/ test.csv 
sh: can't create /storage/: Is a directory
sh: cat: /data/data/: Permission denied
```

また　pullはshell内では使えないということもあったのでshell外からpullを使ってみたのですが引き出されたファイルは0でした。

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>
adb pull     data/data/eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance /files/test.csv C:\csv
pull: building file list...
0 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
```

Comment: catのリダイレクト先に空白スペースが入っているように思えます。

Comment: リダイレクト先のスペースを消したのですがうまくいきません。。。
  cat /data/data/eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance/
  files/test.csv > /storage/sdcard0/test.csv

        /data/data/eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance/                            
        sh: cat: /data/data/eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance/: Is a directory
        s/test.csv > /storage/sdcard0/test.csv                                        
        sh: can't create /storage/sdcard0/test.csv: Permission denied

Comment: run-asでcatで書き出そうとしてPermission deniedになりますでしょうか？（自分も端末なのかバージョン依存なのか追ってませんが、そういうケースに遭遇したことがあるので、/data/data/内のファイルをSDカードに書き出すデバッグ用の処理を追加したことがあります）

Comment: 早速回答して頂きありがとうございます。
はい、run-as内で出てきてしまいます。端末はNexus5です。
もしよろしければ追加した処理を教えていただけませんか？

Comment: 追加した処理は本当に単純に、`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`のパスへファイルをコピーする処理ですね。ちなみに`adb exec-out run-as eyegraphic.nikkeibp.wings.jp.eyeglance cat files/test.csv > test.csv`だとどうなりますか？

Comment: 上記の処理をしたところ
gs.jp.eyeglance cat files/test.csv > test.csv
と表示され、いくら待ってもなんの反応もありませんでした。
また出力先の中を覗こうとしても
sh: cd: //storage/sdcard0: Permission denied
と表示されてしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

こちらはできませんか？

```
adb shell run-as my.package.name cat /file-path/filename | perl -ne 's/\r$//' > out
```

**参考:**
[Androidでadb pullできないデータをスマフォからパソコンに取り出す方法](http://mathematik.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/29/135954)